# How to set up github webhook trigger on pushing in certain branch

Tags: jenkins, github, git-webhooks

I have Jenkins pipeline, and configured github webhook to trigger pipeline.

How to make triggering pipeline when the certain branch was pushed, instead of triggering pipeline by pushing to every branch ?

Comment: I made a php based filter https://gist.github.com/hayden-t/e3a6a85d404897430188368fad53786a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webhook is generic for all, there is no filter on the side github or bitbucket, all you need to handle based on payload.

you can use [Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin),The plugin will allow you to parse certain data from the payload, and can conditionally trigger a build depending on the branch name.

Apply the filter with branch name

[image]

[generic-webhook-trigger-plugin-specific-branch](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/issues/14)

Comment: **important:** I had to specify Jenkins's URL for github webhook in this way `http://some_user:some_password@JENKINS_HOST:JENKINS_PORT/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke`